# CSS3 ASP HTML not working

Tags: html, css

Trying to understand how to get CSS3 styles to work for my classic ASP page if it is possible, (FYI: code idea is from w3schools):

```
...
#rcorners {border-radius: 25px;border: 2px solid #73AD21;padding: 20px;}
...
<form id="rcorners" ...
```

The code shows the box but with no rounded corners.
Using IE11 and my html declared as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
```

is there something else I am missing or something I need to remove?

I did try without the "... PUBLIC ..." declaration however that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

-moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius should be used as border-radius is for CSS3 and you are most probably using CSS2

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am not a web programmer just ask to fix asp/html code I am learning as I go. How do I tell it to use CSS3. I thought as I said in question if I remove the PUBLIC ... declaration it becomes CSS3 (I.e. just <!DOCTYPE HTML>) however I admit my ignorance.

Comment: Further according to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp it is supported in IE11

Comment: Maybe I need to add a meta tag just got to figure out what one if I do need to.

Comment: #rcorners {
-moz-border-radius: 25px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
padding: 20px;
}

Comment: Also, you are here to learn so no stress. This is a support community so feel welcome to ask when get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In the header I applied the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Seems to do the trick!